# Как передать utm в php curl?

Tags: php, php-curl

Как можно передать utm метку в CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы в `post` передаете `json` - кто Вам мешает добаваить в него еще одно (или несколько полей)
`CURL_POSTFIELDS => '{"utm_xxx": "value", "name": "", ...}'`